# Firebase's iOS Offline Capabilities vs Core Data

Tags: ios, firebase

I am developing a small set of classes that will make it easy to keep your Core Data in sync with your Firebase. But, I recently came across [Firebase's iOS Offline Capabilities](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/offline-capabilities.html) and I noticed, regarding data persistence, it sounds to me like similar capabilities that Core Data would provide.

As I said, I am trying to make it easy for my Core Data to stay in sync with my Firebase. How do the two differ (if at all for my case)? More specifically, will Firebase offline provide similar effects? My intentions are for a single-user app, I do not need to support multiple users simultaneously on the same app. I need the data to persist so that users can access their data offline, and between app sessions/restarts.

Comment: The answer here somewhat depends on whether the project is single user or multiple users. i.e. CoreData is really a single-user technology - it doesn't really shine when you want to share live-updating data with other users (yes, you can Push Notification but that's different than live updating).   Firebase on the other hand can do both - single user or thousands of users working with the same dataset.  Can you update your question with more details about the type of usage your app is for? (Single user, multi user, why do you need offline and online storage)

Comment: @Jay, I updated the question.

Answer (score 15):

I work at Firebase, and I once tried to do the same thing.

The Offline Capabilities of Firebase make using CoreData a bit superfluous. Firebase's offline handles a lot of the complexities like dealing with authentication offline and syncing after being offline for long period of time.

It might be useful to have a wrapper around CoreData if you really want to use the two together. However, I have found that it ends up being more complicated than it's really worth.

Comment: We're currently in the process of evaluating Firebase offline capabilities for large data sets (~20k records) and found it somewhat slow. Core Data may handle this better but we haven't tried it yet since we don't want to get the whole stack too complicated. Any word on this?

Comment: Hi David, I'm in the same situation as @Matt and am wondering about offline performance for large datasets in the new Firebase release vs Core Data or Realm. Any thoughts?

Comment: I would also like to get info on FireBase's offline mode. I read somewhere that it isn't that good if the app has been offline for too long. I would like to sync Coredata to Firebase. What does this involve? Maybe use offline capabilities for help syncing?

Answer (score 12):

As an additional answer...Both Core Data and Firebase can both store data 'offline'. They have data persistence and will enable your code to run offline transparently to the user.

To dig a bit deeper, Core Data doesn't have an 'online mode'* (built in) whereas, as soon as Firebase has a connection - wham-o, all of your offline data is now online.  (*CloudKit gives CoreData that online-ness)

Additionally, Firebase has real-time data updates, so if that's what you need Firebase is the way to go for that functionality.

So for your use case, as David mentions, you are duplicating off-line functionality in many ways - especially if this is a single user only use.

If you've already got CoreData & CloudKit working, it may not be worth the time to also loop Firebase into the project - it really depends on the scope of the classes you are building.

Answer (score 3):

I have started with Firebase and stumbled upon these two issues that made me switch back to CoreData:

1. No offline search - Firebase (online or offline) search is very limited, and they recommends using a third party service like Aglolia, which needs another subscription, another offline mode, another authentication etc. CoreData just supports searching via SQL like language and it is easy.
2. No offline attachments - Firebase (real time database or cloudstore) doesn't have offline attachments feature, and Firebase Storage doesn't have an offline mode as well, so I will need to implement this on my own.